# Dependency Inject non-default Entity Manager into Service in Symfony

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I want to change from the default em to an em called 'ps'. The configuration is correct and in the controller I can simply type `$this->getManager('ps')->getConnection('ps');`.

However I want to create a service with dependency injection which also needs to access this connection.

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Service;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class HilaService
{

    private $entityManager;
    private $connection;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->connection = $entityManager->getConnection('ps');

    }

    public function getCategories(){
        $query = $this->connection->query(
            'SQL ....'
        );

        $r = $query->execute();
    }
}
```

As I can nowhere select the Entity Manager 'ps' it can't also load the connection 'ps', which results in an error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'ps_xxx' doesn't exist
```

Can I somehow pass an argument to the injection? Or Inject somewhat of a 'parent object' to then call `->getManager()`?

Comment: All you need is the connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your service class just needs the connection then it easiest way it make your own connection class and inject it.

```
namepace AppBundle\Connection;

class PsConnection extends Doctrine\DBAL\Connection
{
}

# doctrine.yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        connections:
            ps:
                wrapper_class: AppBundle\Connection\PsConnection

# services.yaml
App\:
    resource: '../src/'
    exclude:
        - '../src/AppBundle/Connection/PsConnection.php'

class HilaService
{
    public function __construct(AppBundle\Connection\PsConnection $conn)
```

Everything will work as before but you can get the connection directly.

if you really do need the entity manager then you can make a service definition:

```
# services.yaml
AppBundle\Service\HilaService:
    $entityManager: '@doctrine.orm.ps_entity_manager'
```

Finally, if you don't want to fool around with any of this stuff you can inject the ManagerRegistry and pull what you need from it.

```
class HilaService
{
    public function __construct(Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry $managerRegistry)
    {
        $em = $managerRegistry->getManager('ps'); // or getConnection()
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer. Greatly explained triad of methods, however the first one - which indeed seems to be the nicest - does not work for me: `Cannot autowire service "AppBundle\Connection\PsConnection": argument "$params" of method "Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::__construct()" is type-hinted "array", you should configure its value explicitly.`

Comment: Sorry.  You need to add the Connection directory to the exclude section of services.yaml to prevent it from being picked up by autowire.

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY There are several approaches: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59266372/how-to-use-symfony-autowiring-with-multiple-entity-managers/59289477#59289477 Personally I like the decorator approach but pick whichever works best for you.

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for, thank ! I didn't know about this decorator feature, very useful in that case.